# How to Insert data into Ms.Access using for - next in Vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ms-access

I took data from a MySQL database, and I created an addition Access data base, which is based on the field names of the MySQL database. I want to directly save all record fields to the new Access database, before the connection closes. The problem is that only 1 record is getting stored into my Access database.

This is my code :

```
tbl.Name = "Leger"
cat.Tables.Append(tbl)
tbl.Columns.Append("idsiswa", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger)
tbl.Columns.Append("nama", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 40)
tbl.Columns.Append("nis", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 15)
tbl.Columns.Append("idkelas", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger)
tbl.Columns.Append("tahunpelajaran", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 9)
tbl.Columns.Append("semester", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adInteger)
While RD_pelajaran.Read
    tbl.Columns.Append(RD_pelajaran.Item("kodepelajaran") & "_14_P", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adSingle)
    tbl.Columns.Append(RD_pelajaran.Item("kodepelajaran") & "_H_P", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 3)
    tbl.Columns.Append(RD_pelajaran.Item("kodepelajaran") & "_14_K", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adSingle)
    tbl.Columns.Append(RD_pelajaran.Item("kodepelajaran") & "_H_K", ADOX.DataTypeEnum.adVarWChar, 3)
    Dim koneksi2 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & PathDb)
    koneksi2.Open()
    For xloop = 0 To RD_pelajaran.FieldCount - 1
        Dim vIdsiswa As Integer = RD_pelajaran.Item("idsiswa")
        Dim vNama As String = RD_pelajaran.Item("nama")
        Dim vnis As String = RD_pelajaran.Item("nis")
        Dim vidkelas1 As String = RD_pelajaran.Item("idkelas")
        Dim vtahunpelajaran As String = RD_pelajaran.Item("tahunpelajaran")
        Dim vsemester1 As String = RD_pelajaran.Item("semester")
        Dim Va001ap As Single = RD_pelajaran.Item("nilai_semester_p")
        Dim va001hp As String = RD_pelajaran.Item("nilaihuruf_p")
        Dim Va001ak As Single = RD_pelajaran.Item("nilai_semester_k")
        Dim va001hk As String = RD_pelajaran.Item("nilaihuruf_k")
        Dim InsertData As String = "INSERT INTO Leger(idsiswa,nama,nis,idkelas,tahunpelajaran,semester,A001_14_P,A001_H_P,A001_14_k,A001_H_K) VALUES ('" & vIdsiswa & "','" & vNama & "','" & vnis & "','" & vidkelas1 & "','" & vtahunpelajaran & "','" & vsemester1 & "','" & Va001ap & "','" & va001hp & "','" & Va001ak & "','" & va001hk & "')"
        Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(InsertData, koneksi2)
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
    koneksi2.Close()
End While
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: `xloop` is iterating columns not rows; SQL Parameters would simplify the code immensely and you should use `Option Strict On`

Comment: i try ` x = x + 1
For xloop = 0 To x - 1`
but it's not work for save all field from mysql database, but just one row sir.